# How to use one column value to delete rows on the basis of another column value in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with the following structure:

```
data <- data.table(
  Name = c("orc1", "orc1", "orc1", "orc2", "orc2", "orc4", "orc4", "orc4"),
  Subject = c("apple1", "apple2", "pear", "apple1", "apple2", "ban1", "ban2", "ban3"),
 Cross = c("apple1, apple2", "apple1, apple2", "", "", "", "ban1, ban2, ban3", "ban1, ban2, ban3", "ban1, ban2, ban3"),
 Count = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
)
```

Ultimately, I want to group by Name and summarize by summing the 'Count' variable so that I end up with one row for each value of Name.

Example:

```
Name Count
Orc1   9
Orc2  6
Orc4  12
```

However, the 'Cross' variable tells me that certain values of `Subject` should not to be considered unique and so should not be counted twice when summarizing. For instance, for `orc1` above, `apple1` and `apple2` should only contribute to the total once and not twice. Therefore the sum for `orc1` should be 6 and not 9. And for `orc4` the total sum should be 3.

For my purposes, I can think of at least two solutions that would work:

1. delete rows. Example: for `orc1` use the information in `source` to delete the `orc1` row where `apple2` appears as `subject`.
2. set `Count` to 0. Example: For `orc1`, use the information in `source` to set the `Count` values to 0 for the `orc 1` row where `apple2` appears as `subject`.

So ultimately, I should end up with this:

```
Name Count
Orc1.  6
Orc2   6
Orc4  3
```

I have tried various approaches but consistently get stuck on how to parse the information in a way that can then be used to limit the output.

Comment: Do you just want to sum ```count``` for each ```Name```? That is easy if so. Or do you also need to consider ```subject```?

Comment: @scott.pilgrim.vs.r  In the end, sum `count` for each `name`. `subject` is only used in tandem with `Cross` to limit what is summed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can filter the data for rows with empty cross values or cross values that match the first value listed in the cross description. Using `dplyr` and `stringr` we can do

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  filter(Cross=="" | stringr::str_split_i(Cross, ", ", 1) == Subject) %>% 
  summarize(Count=sum(Count), .by=Name)
#   Name Count
# 1 orc1     6
# 2 orc2     6
# 3 orc4     3
```

This does assume there will always be a record where Name matches the first value listed in the Cross column

Answer (score 2):

Please try the below code

```r
data %>%  
  mutate(new=ifelse(Cross!='',duplicated(Cross), NA)) %>% filter(new %in% c(FALSE, NA)) %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>%
  summarise(Count= sum(Count))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  Name  Count
  <chr> <dbl>
1 orc1      6
2 orc2      6
3 orc4      3
```